# How to pass not exported function from App to child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, function, react-hooks

I created a myFunction in my App.tsx, that refers to some states defined also in App. I need to be able to pass that function to my child component.

**App.tsx**

```
const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([] as CartItemType[]);
const { data, isLoading, error } = useQuery<CartItemType[]>(
    'products',
    getProducts
);
const [itemColor, setItemColor] = useState([]);


    function myFunction(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
    let newData: any[] = [...data!];
    let changedItem = {
        ...data!.find((i) => i.name === selectedData.name),
    };
    let changedItemIndex = data!.findIndex(
        (i) => i.name === selectedData.name
    );
    changedItem.chair!.selected = e.target.value;
    newData[changedItemIndex] = changedItem;
    setItemColor(newData[0]);
    }
```

**Child.tsx**

```
import myFunction from '../App';
 <Item click={myFunction()}></Item>
```

Unfortunately that does not work. I also tried to do it through `props`, but also unsuccessfully.

Component `Item` its just exported function from Child.tsx to keep my code cleaner.

```
function Item(props) {
    let colorHeaderClassName = `selected ${props.click}`;

return (
    <>
        <Button
            onClick={props.click}
            className={colorHeaderClassName}
        />
    </>
);
}
```

Comment: `<Item click={myFunction()}></Item>` just passes the result of _calling_ that function. You want `<Item click={myFunction}></Item>`, and then call the function in the component

Comment: Thanks @Andy but that throws error of invalid hook call.

Comment: There are no hooks in the code you've provided.

Comment: I edited my post @Andy, hooks are hold in `myFunction ` - I hope it's easier now to get what I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
export function myFunction(e) {
   .....
   .....
}
```

```
import {myFunction} from '../App';
```

Comment: This does not work because the function is not exported and I can not export it since in App.tsx I am already exporting App component.

Comment: try  to export default the App component

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.